# Iterate over a list and add the data into another nested list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a problem here:

```
orgn_data = [{ "host1" : [{'port': 8080, 'name': 'data1'}, {'port': 8000, 'name': 'data2'}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'data3'}]},
             {"host2": [{'port': 443, 'name': 'data1'}, {'port': 8000, 'name': 'data2'}]}
            ]

res_data = [{'host1': ['1', '0', '1']}, {'host2': ['1', '0']}]
```

Basically, the res_data is the results list that has the same host as the orgn_data list. I want to merge the res_data for the same host, with the same order into orgn list.
I can guarantee the order of res_data is the same as the orgn_data itself. However, the outer list might not be always the same order as it always(could be multiple hosts). So that means, there has to be looking for hostname first in order to get the correct pair.

The final result should be like below:

```
final_data = [{ "host1" : [{'port': 8080, 'name': 'data1', "status": 1}, {'port': 8000, 'name': 'data2', "status": 0}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'data3', "status": 1}]},
              {"host2": [{'port': 443, 'name': 'data1', "status": 1}, {'port': 8000, 'name': 'data2', "status": 0}]}
             ]
```

What is the best way to do this?  Huge thanks for this!

Comment: Are hostnames unique within a list?

Comment: yes. the host is unique, both lists has the same amount of hosts.

Comment: Every value of `orgn_data` and `res_data` (a dictionary) has only one host?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes. one host only per pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import copy
final_data = copy.deepcopy(orgn_data)
aux_dict = { host:lst for d in res_data for host, lst in d.items() }
# aux_dict == {'host1': ['1', '0', '1'], 'host2': ['1', '0']}
for dct in final_data:
    # dct == { "host1" : [{'port': 8080, 'name': 'data1'}, {'port': 8000, 'name': 'data2'}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'data3'}]} etc.
    for host, lst in dct.items():
    # host == "host1" --> lst == [{'port': 8080, 'name': 'data1'}, {'port': 8000, 'name': 'data2'}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'data3'}]
        for i, subdct in enumerate(lst):
            # i == 0 --> subdct == {'port': 8080, 'name': 'data1'}
            subdct['status'] = aux_dict[host][i]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers already, I add one utilizing `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

for k, (orgn, res) in groupby(sorted(orgn_data + res_data, key=lambda k: [*k.keys()][0]), lambda k: [*k.keys()][0]):
    for v, s in zip(orgn[k], res[k]):
        v['status'] = s

print(orgn_data)
```

Prints:

```
[{'host1': [{'port': 8080, 'name': 'data1', 'status': '1'}, {'port': 8000, 'name': 'data2', 'status': '0'}, {'port': 80, 'name': 'data3', 'status': '1'}]}, 
 {'host2': [{'port': 443, 'name': 'data1', 'status': '1'}, {'port': 8000, 'name': 'data2', 'status': '0'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is quite a short line to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to update `orgn_data` to include the `status` key:

```
order = lambda x: next(iter(x.keys()))
for org, res in zip(*map(lambda lst: sorted(lst, key=order), (orgn_data, res_data))):
  for key, lst in org.items():
    for i, inner in enumerate(lst):
      inner['status'] = res[key][i]
```

Result:

```
[{'host1': [{'name': 'data1', 'port': 8080, 'status': '1'},
            {'name': 'data2', 'port': 8000, 'status': '0'},
            {'name': 'data3', 'port': 80, 'status': '1'}]},
 {'host2': [{'name': 'data1', 'port': 443, 'status': '1'},
            {'name': 'data2', 'port': 8000, 'status': '0'}]}]
```

If you want a copy of the data, the other answer got you better covered. 
 But if you're feeling adventurous and crazy you can try this:

```
order = lambda x: next(iter(x.keys()))

final_data = [
  {key: [
    {k: v for k, v in list(inner.items()) + [('status', res[key][i])]}
    for i, inner in enumerate(lst)
    ]
  }
  for org, res in zip(*map(lambda lst: sorted(lst, key=order), (orgn_data, res_data)))
  for key, lst in org.items()
]
```

[Sample code](https://repl.it/repls/FaintGiftedDisks)